# Crop a raster image to specified longitude and latitude?

Tags: r, clipping

I have a stack of raster image and I want to crop them on specified longitude and latitude. when I run my code it gives me error.

```
    library(raster)
    raster_crop <-crop("my_path",ext_focal)
    ext_focal <-extent(50,55,-70,-73)
```

#after second line I got this erroe
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘crop’ for signature ‘"character"’> e

What wrong in this code or I need to find other code for cropping?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an extent (defined after the fact) to crop a character string. Very curious indeed. The error message tells you that this is not possible. There is no method to crop a character string.

You can do something like this instead.

```
library(raster)
e <-extent(50, 55, -70, -73)
r <- raster("my_path")
raster_crop <-crop(r, e)
```